# Adding custom key-value pair in json output Grape and Rabl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, ruby-on-rails-4, rabl, grape-api

I am building an API with Rails. The gems I use to build api are Grape and Rabl. I have done a lot of work but now I have to add `status` flag before all the json response from the api. How could I do this?

I have this `.rabl` file.

```
object @current_parent

attributes :first_name => :name
attributes :cell_phone => :mobile
attributes :email
attributes :address

node :day_care do |m| 
{ 
  :name     => current_day_care.name, 
  :address  => current_day_care.address, 
  :phone    => current_day_care.office_phone,
  :website  => current_day_care.website,
  :logo     => current_day_care.logo.url,
  :no_of_child => current_parent.relatives.count
}
end


child :relatives, :object_root => false do |m|
  child :child, :object_root => false do |n|
    attributes :id
    attributes :first_name      =>  :name
    attributes :gender
    attributes :student_stage   =>  :classroom
  end
end
```

This makes the the following output

```
{
"parent": {
    "name": "Devan",
    "mobile": "1234567891",
    "email": "testparent1@mail.com",
    "address": "762 Beahan Expressway",
    "day_care": {
        "name": "Brisa Erdman",
        "address": "859 Hermann Summit",
        "phone": "915.758.4580",
        "website": "fisher.info",
        "logo": "/uploads/day_care/logo/1/http%3A/example.com/ally",
        "no_of_child": 2
    },
    "relatives": [
        {
            "child": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Lucious",
                "gender": "t",
                "classroom": "PreKindergarten"
            }
        },
        {
            "child": {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Lilly",
                "gender": "t",
                "classroom": "Toddlers"
            }
        }
    ]
}
}
```

But I want to have `status` flag in the beginning before the `parent` opens up like below

```
{
"status": "Success"
"parent": {
    "name": "Devan",
    "mobile": "1234567891",
    "email": "testparent1@mail.com",
```

But I cant figure out how to make this happen using rabl. Please guide me through this. If not possible provide an alternative solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take your current `parent.rabl` file, and use it as a partial in a new rabl template that expresses the status.

```
 object false
 node :parent do
    partial("parent", :object => @parent)
 end
 node :status  do
   @status
 end
```

then call this rabl file from your controller

Comment: This one works. Thanks a lot blotto. I have also figured out another way for this. Will post my answer too.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks blotto for your answer. I figured out another solution for my problem and it seem to suite my situation ie not needed to create extra file and call the original `parent.rabl` as partial. This way my number of view files would be same. Have a look

Solution parent.rabl file

```
node do |u|
{
  :status => "Success"
}
end
child @current_parent do 

attributes :first_name => :name
attributes :cell_phone => :mobile
attributes :email
attributes :address

node :day_care do |m| 
{ 
  :name     => current_day_care.name, 
  :address  => current_day_care.address, 
  :phone    => current_day_care.office_phone,
  :website  => current_day_care.website,
  :logo     => current_day_care.logo.url,
  :no_of_child => current_parent.relatives.count
}
end

child :relatives, :object_root => false do |m|
  child :child, :object_root => false do |n|
    attributes :id
    attributes :first_name      =>  :name
    attributes :gender
    attributes :student_stage   =>  :classroom
  end
end 
end
```

By this way I get my desired result.